# Rails - Check Boxes Calling Methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I'm making a 'check_list' for my company.  Each row of the table will be ONE event with 10+ check boxes that are labeled with the table header.  Each time a check box is clicked I want to save that user's ID and Date.  Is there a way to call a server side method to save this without submitting a form?

I just don't want to use a submit button because I need as much room as possible for check boxes.

I welcome any ideas or tips/tricks.

I am using Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery, attach to the change event, and use ajax to call the method.